# Get list of physical screens with resolutions in Node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, x11

I have 2+ physical monitors (1680x1050, 1920x1080), grouped in one "screen" (3600 x 1080):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3600 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1680x1050+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.88*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94
```

I would like to find out list of screens with dimensions. Limitation to X11 \ GTK is completely ok for me.

I already tried `screen-info` and `node-x11` (both outputs single 3600 x 1080 screen). I know there maybe some useful bindings in NW.js and Electron, but my app is not supposed to use this wrappers.

Of course, I could parse raw `xrandr` output, but my question is if there is some more convenient way to do this.

Comment: there is xrandr parser module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/xrandr (node-x11 author here, happy to answer questions re node-x11 )

Comment: Missed that package, seems better that manual parsing. Thanks!